# Web Control TreeView select a Node programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I use asp.net 4 and c#.
I have a TreeView and I would like select an existing node programmtically.

```
SelectNode() method is read only
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednode.aspx

so I do not know how to do it.
Please reply for a TreeView WEB CONTROL not for Win App.

My Code:

```
protected void uxTreeView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView myTreeView = (TreeView)uxManageSlotsDisplayer.FindControl("uxTreeView");
    myTreeView.Nodes[2].Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.selected.aspx) property of a particular TreeNode.

Comment: Hi, which event for the treeview shall I use after all the nodes are added to select a specif node? thanks in advanced

Comment: It depend on how you populate the treeview. If you are data binding it - use the DataBound event, find the node of interest and select it.

Comment: I use OnTreeNodePopulate and some logic to retrive the nodes value from my database. DataBound should work? I am testing now but it seems that DataBound does not work. any ideas? thanks

Comment: DataBound works only when you are databinding. What prevents you from setting the Selected property?

Comment: I am not DataBinding but i populate nodes programatically. So in DataBound I cannot find any Proprieties to allow me to select a node.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't set the Selected property of the required node. Without explaining this I cannot help any further. Please edit your question by including some code and explain why you cannot set the Selected property of the node.

Comment: I posted my code for DataBound, first im not able to retrive the TreeView so I cannot select a node. I think this is the problem. Thanks for your time on this